# How array_shift works inside array_push

Tags: php

```
function leftShift($arr, $num) {
  for ($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
    array_push($arr, array_shift($arr)); //How this works 
    /*  
     What value does parameter one has  
     how array_shift works inside the array push second parameter.
     array_shift($arr) = 2,3,4
     $arr = 1,2,3,4
     if it goes inside array_push how it works.
     */
   }
  return $arr;
 }

function rightShift($arr, $num) {
   for ($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
      array_unshift($arr, array_pop($arr)); //How this works 
      /* Please explain this logic too..*/
  }
     return $arr;
 }
```

**leftShift([1, 2, 3, 4], 1) ➞ [2, 3, 4, 1]
rightShift([1, 2, 3, 4], 1) ➞ [4, 1, 2, 3]**

array_pop() pops an element off end of the array.

array_push() pushes an element into the end of the array.

array_shift() pops an element off the beginning of the array.

array_unshift() pushes an element into the beginning of the array.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you tried to work this out for yourself - what do you think happens when you `array_shift()` an item and then with this item you use  `array_push()`?

Comment: is it a question? please elaborate?

Comment: @NigelRen i got this code from internet for this problem. I dont know the mechanism behind this. please help if you know. Thanks

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie , I don't know the mechanism how array_push(array,array_shift($array)) if it works what the parameter 1 contains , what parameter 2 contains. lets assume the results of this array_push([1,2,3,4],[2,3,4]); then how the output is  [2, 3, 4, 1]  is generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should note that two things happen after calling some functions like `array_push` or `array_shift`, they change the array in the way you explained but **do not return the result**, instead change the variable which is passed by reference to them, and return another thing which is also helpful. what does `array_shift` do is simply shifting the inputed variable left by one and return the removed element. Let's look at the following code

```
$arr = [1,2,3,4];
$x = array_shift($arr);
print_r($arr);
echo $x;
```

The result would be

```
[2, 3, 4]
1
```

Note if you write `array_shift([1,2,3,4]);` you'll receive an error because you need to pass a variable to `array_shift` function, it wants to change the reference variable.

---

The second important thing is for evaluating a function, compiler needs to evaluate the arguments first. So when she wants to execute the following line

```
array_push($arr, array_shift($arr));
```

she first needs to evaluate `$arr` (which is already evaluated) and `array_shift($arr)`. But evaluation of `array_shift($arr)` results in side-effect, changing the content of `$arr`. So what happens is first she calls the `array_shift` function, after this step we have `$arr = [2, 3, 4]` and `array_shift($arr) = 1` now the mentioned line is like

```
array_push([2, 3, 4], 1);
```

(Note the above code is actually an error because `array_push` also needs a variable and will change its contents but writing like this would help understanding.)

now what this function do is to push the second parameter `1` into the first parameter `[2, 3, 4]` and put the result inside the first parameter `$arr` actually. the result is the state in which `$arr` is `[2, 3, 4, 1]`. *Voilà*.

(Note that there is no need to write `$arr = array_push(...);`, the `array_push` eventually changes its first parameter. Actually it's an error, `array_push` will return *new number of elements in the array*, so if you write `$arr = array_push(...);` the variable `$arr` will become the integer 4.)

---

The function does the same thing as many times as it is asked to do. And I assume you can now explain the logic of the second function `rightShift` by yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much its a awesome explanation.

Answer (score 4):

[image: You see with this picture how is it work.]

You see with this picture how is it work. With line 3 **array_shift** remove and **store** **fist item** of array now array **missing** from first item, with **array_push** adding end of array **stored** item, this is a loop until **$num**, With line 17 **array_pop** remove and store last item of array, now array **missing** from last item, with **array_unshift** adding first of new array **stored** item, this is a loop and until **$num**